# Tests execution crosses the midnight edge

Tags: apex, unit-test, datetime

Our tests are scheduled to be run in production on a daily basis.
They usually starts let's say one hour before midnight and finishes one hour after midnight. And from time to time we are experiencing random test failures of random test methods, i.e. every time it's another test method, different class, part of business logic etc. (or if we are lucky everything executes successfully).

The only pattern we were able to identify is that failure always relates to invalid value of some date fields or formulas which relies on date calculation.

Our best guess: test method starts executing one day (one second before midnight and some test data are created using System.today() for some fields, business logic runs) and then results assertion happens next day (i.e. System.today() points to another date already).

We've tried to fix this by catching today's date at the beginning of the test method execution and kinda freeze it using wrappers/mocks/proxy whatever we could call it. As result failures almost disappeared (just 1-2 per week). The problem is that we have a lot of formulas in the system which uses TODAY() value and we can not mock it with our custom solution (same way as we did inside apex test code).

Is there anyway to mock date and time at the system/global level?
Or maybe there is better idea how to handle this date/time bombs?

Rescheduling tests execution is not an option, cause according to our clients they have no control over it, i.e. no options to specify execution time in their test execution solution(

Bellow is the example of test method which could trigger such midnight problem (no even business logic here):

```
// executes before midnight: today = Aug 1
Account originalAccount =
    new Account(
        External_Date__c = System.today()
    )
;


insert originalAccount;


Test.startTest();

Test.stopTest();

// executes after midnight: : today = Aug 2
Account actualAccount = [ SELECT Id, External_Date__c, Internal_Formula_Date__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :originalAccount.Id ];

// fails because Aug 1 != Aug 2; but we can mock this in our code
System.assert(System.today(), actualAccount.External_Date__c);

// fails as well. Internal_Formula_Date__c is defined as TODAY(), so we can not mock this!!!
System.assert(System.today(), actualAccount.Internal_Formula_Date__c);
```

Comment: Instead of trying some hack I suggest you to check the code and see if you can handle this at code level as well.

Comment: nice point, @TusharSharma! one thing to remember -- if test fails sometimes in midnight, that mean that some business logic may fail in midnight, so be careful around that

Comment: @TusharSharma Updated my question with test method example. Let's leave business logic aside.

Comment: Can you please add the code of Internal_Formula_Date__c formula field, as this can also be mocked

Comment: Have you considered asserting against the `CreatedDate` of the `Account` instead of `system.today()`?

Comment: @SantanuBoral Internal_Formula_Date__c: TODAY(). I don't know how to mock today inside formula, that's the problem)

Comment: @DerekF Yep, your suggestion would work for this particular example. But I have hundreds of tests with dates calculation, which are not so simple as provided example, i.e. CreatedDate works for a very specific use case. Also there are some boolean formulas which relies on today, e.g. Is_August__c. Could assert such thing only for true or false. Need more universal solution to mock somehow dates inside formulas, but just in the test scope.

Comment: I think you are creating your own problems here. Why are you asserting the value of the date field that you just set using a relative value. If you set it then assert the value is as set it not a relative value. The other issue is hard to say as we do not have a good example

Answer (score 4):

For Apex code, change all your references from `Date.today()` and `System.now()` to `Util.today` and `Util.now`. Where ...

```
public static Date today {
     get { return today == null ? Date.today() : today; }
     set;
  }
  public static DateTime now {
     get { return now == null ? System.now() : now; }
     set;
  }
```

For formulas and VRs ..

1. Create a hierarchical custom setting `TestSettings` with two fields: `MockedToday` and `MockedNow` of appropriate types
2. Change references in formula fields from `TODAY()` to `BLANKVALUE($Setup.TestSettings__c.MockToday__c,TODAY())` and equivalent for `NOW()`

Then, in your test methods - mock the Apex value and the hierarchical settings to "some invariant for the testmethod" date and datetime value

If you have zillions of references to TODAY() in formulas, change only those that affect your testmethods running across midnight threshold.

Comment: Regarding System.today & Utils, yep, that's exactly what we've done, i.e. wrapper around system methods with mocking capabilities. Got your point re formulas & validation rules. Thinking how to minimize the amount of changes, cause don't wanna modify almost every test & formula. Theoretically all formulas with direct on indirect usage of today are impacted, they just happen not to fail by luck (i.e. test method starts and ends at the same day, which could be not the truth for next test run). How nice it would be to have Test.setToday() at the system level, which covers everything, just dreams)

Comment: One more thing, there are few formulas in the system, which basically can not be modified by adding new stuff. They are too close to 5000 characters limit. That's of course separate problem by itself. It's just make it harder to introduce mocking at the formula's level.

Comment: `BLANKVALUE(..)` is a lightweight function but I get your point

Comment: Registered an idea to introduce date/time mocking support at the system level: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEaPQAU

Comment: @wesaw - nicely done, have you seen this? https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/07/30/help-salesforce-help-us-writing-a-good-idea-exchange-post/ - Looks like you adhered to it well

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how many system date related formula fields you are using.
This could be the workaround for formula field.

Create 2 fields:

`Is_Testing__c` boolean field (default `false`) and from your test method, make it `TRUE`.

`Test_System_Date__c`date field, which you can assign value from test method.

Change `Internal_Formula_Date__c` like this:

`IF(Is_Testing__c,Test_System_Date__c,TODAY())`

So in your test method it will give you expected value.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks. Unfortunately, there are dozens of fields like that on different objects; formulas are sometimes really complex inside and quite close to length limit (5000 symbols). Thinking how to tune this to make it work at a large scale without a lot of formula updates.

Comment: Why you are querying the data? rather you can create data in test class and execute test method.